# My Email Newsletter plugin will not configure when I try to import the widget

Tags: widgets, email

I am currently using the "Spun" theme for my website and bluehost as my hosting product. I downloaded and activated the "Email Newsletter" plugin, however when I try to import the widget it does not show up on my website. Is this theme not compatible for email subscriptions? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: What did the plugin author say?

Comment: I cannot find a way to contact the author. Do you have a plug in that you recommend or a theme that works well for an email subscription plugin that you would recommend?

Comment: It has a support forum..?  http://wordpress.org/plugins/email-newsletter/

Comment: I suggest using a reputable email list service like mailchimp or campaign monitor and not trying to do this yourself from your own domain. Successfully sending a high volume of email is not trivial, and it's very easy to land your domain on spam blacklists. Both of the services I've mentioned have plugins to allow users to subscribe and unsubscribe from your list via your site.